# Select statement on left hand side of where condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Would it be a problem if select query is on left hand side of where clause rather than right hand side which we usually use.

```
select * from ABC A where (select ID from XYZ) in (A.ID, A.PID);
```

Is it okay to have *select* query in left hand side of query?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please elaborate it. Also, sample data and expected result would help .

Comment: Actually I need a query select * from ABC A where A.ID in (select ID from XYZ) or A.PID in (select ID from XYZ) but I don't want two subqueries as it might slow down the process

Comment: Here's a silly question (or three :) Did you try running your query? If you did, did you get an error? If you did get an error, can you post it?

Comment: @Abra This query is working. But I just want to know if is this a good idea that's all

Comment: @SYMA this query is not working if your subquery returns more than one row: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cb3269167c9e808fd3688f087a02b5f3

Comment: My subQuery will return only one row I am sure about it

Comment: _My subQuery will return only one row I am sure about it_ That's what the people who wrote software for the [Ariane 5 rocket](https://blog.bugsnag.com/bug-day-ariane-5-disaster/) thought and when their assumption proved wrong, hundreds of millions of dollars went up in smoke! Maybe you should consider the possibility that your assumption may be wrong.

Comment: haha true that :)

Comment: It's not wrong to write the query as you have, but it is unusual. I would go with Gordon's answer of using EXISTS instead - this has the advantage of not erroring, should there be more than one row in XYZ.

Answer (score 2):

I think `exists` does what you want:

```
select a.*
from ABC a
where exists (select 1
              from XYZ x
              where x.id in (A.ID, A.PID)
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this using `JOIN`

```
select * 
from   ABC
left join  XYZ on ABC.ID = XYZ.ID or ABC.PID = XYZ.ID
```

Comment: That returns something different, you can't always replace an IN condition with a JOIN

Comment: The table ABC has two column ABC.ID and ABC.PID and both of them are checking for the value in XYZ.ID. So just joining both the table would give the expected output instead of writing subquery twice.

Comment: Not if that results in multiple matches

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing called `INNER JOIN` for this problem.

```
select A.* 
from ABC A
INNER JOIN XYZ X ON X.ID = A.ID OR X.ID = A.PID
```

No need for any where clause as this will filter the results.

OR you can achieve that by doing this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ABC
WHERE 
ABC.ID IN (select ID from XYZ) 
OR ABC.PID IN (select ID from XYZ)
```

But the first solution should be preferred.

Comment: Yeah I know about INNER JOIN but want to know what is wrong with WHERE clause

Comment: You're trying to select values by using sub query on the left hand side of the where clause, Where clause needs a field to apply filters. WHERE <fieldname> IN (values)

Comment: Yes and in your second query you can see that I am writing same subquery twice. My subqueries are bit long so writing them twice can impact performance.

Comment: Exactly for the performance reasons that you need to use INNER JOIN.

Comment: okay so my question is::select * from ABC A where (select ID from XYZ) in (A.ID, A.PID); Is this approach wrong?

Comment: A query with an IN condition cannot always be written as an INNER JOIN. The inner join changes the meaning of the query.

Comment: I'm not saying INNER JOIN can always replace IN condition in where clause, I specifically said "for this problem".